# Vue3 and Pinia: store state is undefined in other stores

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, undefined, store, pinia

I want to get `users` in **threadStore** from **userStore**, but `users` is `undefined`. And I have no idea why.
Also in **userStore** `threads` from **threadStore** has a correct value.
Maybe that because **threadStore** installed first than **userStore**?
But how I can get **users** from **userStore** in **threadStore**?

[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH6f4.png)

**thread.js**

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useUserStore } from './user';

export const useThreadStore = defineStore('thread', () => {
  const userStore = useUserStore();
  console.log(userStore.users); // is undefined

  const threads = ref([]);

return {
  threads,
}
```

**user.js**

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useThreadStore } from './thread';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  const threadStore = useThreadStore();
  console.log(threadStore.threads); // has a correct value

  const users = ref([]);
  
  return {
    users,
  };
});
```

Comment: You obviously will have problems when using them like that. This is circular dependency in action. You physically can have both of them initialized at `console.log`, because either of them won't reach `return` statement at this point. This is XY problem. Consider reasking the question and explaining your case and what you want to achieve in the end.